# How can I solve $x = e^{a+bx} + c?$

Tags: calculus, lambert-w, implicit-function

I need to solve this implicit equation for a physical system. I know that the similar equation $x = xe^x$ (solved with the Lambert W-function) doesn't have real roots, but since this equation has additional constants it should have real roots. However, my background in these type of equations isn't great so I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The LambertW function will help you $$x=-{\frac {-bc+{\rm W} \left(-b{{\rm e}^{bc+a}}\right)}{b}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as

$$b(x-c) = be^{a+bc} e^{b(x-c)}$$

$$-b(x-c) e^{-b(x-c)} = -be^{a+bc}$$

$$-b(x-c) = W(-be^{a+bc})$$

$$x = c - \frac{1}{b} W(-be^{a+bc})$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can I then computationally calculate $W$ with the infinite sum given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions. And stop at say k = 1000? Or is it better to use Numerical Evaluation like these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation ?

Comment: @BasdeJong I'd say that the method in "Numerical evaluation" section based on Newton iteration is better.